# Task.WhenAny with timeout waits more than timeout value

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this block of code:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
HttpRequestInfo.AddTimestamp("Connecting");
await Task.WhenAny(client.ConnectAsync(serverAddress, serverPort),
                   Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)));
HttpRequestInfo.AddTimestamp("Connected");
if(client.Connected){ ... }
```

Where HttpRequestInfo.AddTimestamp simply logs named timestamps with Stopwatch class.

In logs I sometimes see:

```
"Connecting":110ms - "Connected":747ms
"Connecting":35ms - "Connected":3120ms
"Connecting":38ms - "Connected":3053ms
```

I assumed that this approach will give me the opportunity to limit the connection by timeout (300ms). However, I see that this line of code sometimes (very rarely) runs longer than 300 ms.
What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> This method depends on the system clock. This means that the time
>   delay will approximately equal the resolution of the system clock if
>   the delay argument is less than the resolution of the system clock,
>   which is approximately 15 milliseconds on Windows systems.

So it can explain the longer timeouts if they are approximately 15 milliseconds more than 300 milliseconds, because the delay will have to adjust itself to the system clock resolution.

It does not explain your longer timeouts that are in a larger scale.
I assume that for some reason `ConnectAsync` may block for a while before returning to the calling method, if it is true it will take time between your first log and when you actually fire `Task.Delay` and the problem is not related to the delay at all.

You can try this code and monitor the logs, maybe the lost time is hiding when launching `ConnectAsync`:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
HttpRequestInfo.AddTimestamp("Launching ConnectAsync");
var connectAsyncTask = client.ConnectAsync(serverAddress, serverPort);
HttpRequestInfo.AddTimestamp("ConnectAsync launched");
HttpRequestInfo.AddTimestamp("Launching Delay");
var delayTask= Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
HttpRequestInfo.AddTimestamp("Delay launched");
var firstTask = await Task.WhenAny(connectAsyncTask, delayTask);
if(firstTask == connectAsyncTask)
{ 
    HttpRequestInfo.AddTimestamp("Connected");
}
else
{
    HttpRequestInfo.AddTimestamp("Timeout");
}
```

Comment: In this case, as I understand, the delay can be about 285 - 315 ms. But in my case the method is executed about 3015 ms (3053-38 for example).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to make timestamps in this way. However, it seems to me that the result does not change.